# This query works in postgres and but not in oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, oracle10g, http-post

```
    SELECT 
    DateTo,(((((DATE_PART('Year',DateTo))-(DATE_PART('Year',DateFrom)))*12)+(DATE_PART('Month',DateTo))-(DATE_PART('Month',DateFrom)))+1) AS NoOfMonth
 FROM HT_LoanSusp
```

This query works in postgres and but not in oracle. This is due to date_part function that does not support in oracle.

So I need a function that works in both oracle and postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT` function which exists in both databases:

- [EXTRACT (datetime) in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm)
- [EXTRACT (field FROM source) in PosgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Then your query:

```
SELECT 
    DateTo,(((((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Ht_LoanSusp.DateTo))-(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Ht_LoanSusp.DateFrom)))*12)+
    (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Ht_LoanSusp.DateTo))-(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Ht_LoanSusp.DateFrom)))+1) AS NoOfMonth
 FROM HT_LoanSusp
```